# My query filtering is not working the way I want it to

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtering, table-valued-parameters

I have 3 ways I want to filter:

1. by name
2. by list
3. and show all

I'm using ASP.NET 3.5 and SQL Server 2008. Using ADO.NET and stored procs.

I'm passing my list as a table valued parameter (but I'm testing with a table variable) and the name as a nvarchar. I have "show all" as ISNULL(@var, column) = column. Obviously the way I'm querying this is not taking advantage of short circuiting or my understanding of how WHERE clauses work is lacking. What's happening is if I make @var = 'some string' and insert a null to the table variable, then it filters correctly. If I make @var = null and insert 'some string' to the table variable, then I get every record, where I should be getting 'some string'.

The code:

```
declare @resp1 nvarchar(32)
set @resp1 = null
declare @usersTable table
(responsible nvarchar(32))
--insert into @usersTable (responsible) values (null)
insert into @usersTable (responsible) values ('ssimpson')
insert into @usersTable (responsible) values ('kwilcox')
select uT.responsible, jsq.jobnumber, jsq.qid, aq.question, aq.section, aq.seq, answers.* 
from answers
inner join jobno_specific_questions as jsq on answers.jqid = jsq.jqid
inner join apqp_questions as aq on jsq.qid = aq.qid
left join @usersTable as uT on uT.responsible = answers.responsible
where answers.taskAction = 1 and (uT.responsible is not null or ISNULL(@resp1, Answers.responsible) = Answers.responsible)
order by aq.section, jsq.jobnumber, answers.priority, aq.seq
```

This is what I've come up with. It's ugly though....

```
declare @resp1 nvarchar(32)
set @resp1 = 'rrox'
declare @filterPick int
declare @usersTable table
(responsible nvarchar(32))
insert into @usersTable (responsible) values (null)
--insert into @usersTable (responsible) values ('ssimpson')
--insert into @usersTable (responsible) values ('kwilcox')
if @resp1 is null 
begin
   set @filterPick = 2
end
else
begin
   set @filterPick = 1
end
select uT.responsible, jsq.jobnumber, jsq.qid, aq.question, aq.section, aq.seq, answers.* 
from answers
inner join jobno_specific_questions as jsq on answers.jqid = jsq.jqid
inner join apqp_questions as aq on jsq.qid = aq.qid
left join @usersTable as uT on uT.responsible = answers.responsible
where answers.taskAction = 1 and 
(case
    when uT.responsible is not null then 2
    when ISNULL(@resp1, Answers.responsible) = Answers.responsible then 1          
 end = @filterPick )
order by aq.section, jsq.jobnumber, answers.priority, aq.seq
```

Ok. I think I've got it. I've removed @resp1 because it wasn't necessary and am just using the table valued parameter @usersTable (but here I'm using a table variable for testing). I've added a flag @filterPick so I can show only values in @usersTable or every record where answers.taskAction = 1.

The code:

```
declare @filterPick bit 
declare @usersTable table
(responsible nvarchar(32))
insert into @usersTable (responsible) values (null)
--insert into @usersTable (responsible) values ('ssimpson')
--insert into @usersTable (responsible) values ('kwilcox')
if exists (select * from @usersTable where responsible is not null)
   begin
      set @filterPick = 1
   end
else
   begin
      set @filterPick = 0
   end
select *
from answers
inner join jobno_specific_questions as jsq on answers.jqid = jsq.jqid
inner join apqp_questions as aq on jsq.qid = aq.qid
left join @usersTable as uT on answers.responsible = uT.responsible
where answers.taskAction = 1 and (uT.responsible is not null or (isnull(uT.responsible, answers.responsible) = answers.responsible and @filterPick = 0))
order by aq.section, jsq.jobnumber, answers.priority, aq.seq
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that you are working with?  I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to ask.  Also, I do not believe SQL Server uses any short circuiting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381224/sql-server-query-short-circuiting

Comment: On what exactly are you trying to filter?  You seem to have both a variable (@resp1 in your script) and a table.  So, you want a filter on the @resp1 variable if it is not null or a filter on everything in the table if @resp1 is null?

Comment: I am trying to filter on either @resp1 OR @userTable. So either filter by one name OR by a list of names.

Comment: @Andrew: yes that's what I was trying to do. It didn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by your question but I'll give it a shot.

First off i suspect your issues with the incorrect records being returned have to do with your comparison of a null value.  To demonstrate what I am talking about query any table you want and add this to the end:

```
WHERE null = null
```

no records will be returned.  In your code I would change:

```
where answers.taskAction = 1 and (uT.responsible is not null or ISNULL(@resp1, Answers.responsible) = Answers.responsible)
```

to

```
where answers.taskAction = 1 and (uT.responsible is not null or @resp1 is null)
```

And see if that returns the desired result.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. But I don't where I'm comparing nulls. the ISNULL returns the first non-null value correct?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing the WHERE clause to something like:

```
WHERE Answers.taskAction = 1 
AND(ISNULL(@resp1, Answers.responsible) = Answers.responsible 
    OR Answers.responsible IN (SELECT responsible FROM uT))
```

Instead of JOINing on the table-valued parameter?