# SQL searching based on comparing keyword against multiple columns, but to avoid Conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've an SQL statment like this

```
declare @keyword varchar(100)='ndee'
select ISNUMERIC(@keyword)

select * from teststaken where ( 
   (firstname like '%' + @keyword + '%') or  
   (lastname like '%' + @keyword + '%') or  
    TestTakerEmail like '%' + @keyword + '%' or 
   (ISNUMERIC(@keyword)=1 and TestsTakenID = @keyword)
)
```

Its only a searching query for selecting rows based on a keyword given against different columns. But the teststakenID column is integer. So it works fine if we avoid the last comparison when a string is given. If a string or a word is given it throws an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'andee' to data
>   type int.

But what I tried to accomplish was checking the keyword is integer type or not and only integer type then compare with the teststakenid column. Please help me to find what I did wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @keyword varchar(100)='ndee'

select * 
from teststaken 
where firstname like '%' + @keyword + '%' 
or lastname like '%' + @keyword + '%' 
or TestTakerEmail like '%' + @keyword + '%' 
or cast(TestsTakenID as varchar(100)) = @keyword
```

Explanation: 
You get this exception since Sql server tries to evaluate every condition on your where clause, even if it's after an `and` keyword (unlike c# when using `&&` or vb.net when using `AndAlso`).
This results in an attempt to evaluate the int value of `TestsTakenID` to the varchar value of `@Keyword`.

Since any integer value can be converted to a varchar value providing it's length is sufficient, you can simply cast the `TestsTakenID` to varchar(100) (since it's the length of your parameter anyway). once we do that, there is really no need for the `ISNUMERIC` test as paul rightfully wrote in the comments.
Thanks to [paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280587/paul) and [LittleBooby tables](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334849/littlebobbytables) for the comments, I've learned [something new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381224/sql-server-query-short-circuiting) today :-).

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables `(isnumeric(@keyword) = 1 and cast(@keyword as int) = TestsTakenID)` works just fine for me

Comment: @paul - well what the crap.  based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated), I was always under the impression SQL Server didn't do short-circuiting, outside of `CASE` expressions, but I tested the SQL example, and retract my previous statement.  Very surprised by this.  Either something has changed in SQL Server, or I wouldn't expect this to be reliably consistent.

Comment: @Zohar - that's what I get for doubting myself.  See the link in my response to Paul; short-circuiting can't always be guaranteed in SQL Server, and you're seeing this in the SQL Fiddle.  Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381224/sql-server-query-short-circuiting) for a SQL Server-specific question and answer.

Comment: Well, in that case, I should probably rollback my edits :-) btw, I love your username. I'm always using `Exploits of a Mom` as a link to explain sql injection attacks.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - eeyup :)